# When should we prefer wide-character strings?

Tags: c++, string, mfc, com, widestring

I am modernizing a large, legacy MFC codebase which contains a veritable medley of string types:

- CString
- std::string
- std::wstring
- char*
- wchar_t*
- _bstr_t

I'd like to standardize on a single string type internally, and convert to other types *only when absolutely required* by a third-party API (i.e. COM or MFC functions).  The question my coworkers and I are debating; which string type should we standardize on?

I would prefer one of the C++ standard strings: std::string or std::wstring.  I'm personally leaning toward std::string, because we do not have any need for wide characters - it is an internal codebase with no customer-facing UI (i.e. no need for multiple-language support).  "Plain" strings allow us to use simple, unadorned string literals ("Hello world" vs L"Hello world" or _T("Hello world")).

Is there an official stance from the programming community?  When faced with multiple string types, what is typically used as the standard 'internal' storage format?

Comment: "UTF8 everywhere" comes to mind. But Windows isn't UTF8-friendly. Note however that you really should treat _file names_ as distinct types. Using boost may be a good choice.

Comment: Windows internally is UTF-16LE so `std::wstring` is a good fit for that platform; so is `std::vector<wchar_t>`.

Comment: For a Windows application use `std::wstring`. With narrow strings you'd need conversions all over the place. Note: since you don't already know this, you're not a good choice for person to do the job, it's basics. That choice is your manager's fault.

Comment: Windows provides narrow-char alternatives for nearly all APIs.  In-code conversions would not be necessary.  They may be performed behind the scenes, but that's not really a concern.  It reeks of premature micro-optimizations.

Comment: Re `_T("Hello world")`, the `T` macros were obsoleted in the year 2000 by the introduction of Layer for Unicode, and today our tools can't produce executables for the Windows versions (9x) that these macros target. I understand it's a legacy codebase. But when your task is to **clean it up**, mentioning `T` macros as convenient is absurd and very counter-productive.

Comment: If you choose narrow chars then all you need to break your program is one employee with a non-latin name and you hit encoding problems for the user and below directories.

Comment: http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: @BTownTKD I see a general tendency of newer APIs to provide a wide-char interface only.

Comment: Things like bstr_t you'll need when you're interacting with COM and windows provides various functions to create them.  Elsewhere you should just use std::wstring and wchar_t if you're coding for Windows exclusively.  It's easier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we talk about Windows, than I'd use std::wstring (because we often need cool string features), or wchar_t* if you just pass strings around.

Note Microsoft recommends that here: [Working with Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407.aspx)

> Windows natively supports Unicode strings for UI elements, file names,
>   and so forth. Unicode is the preferred character encoding, because it
>   supports all character sets and languages. Windows represents Unicode
>   characters using UTF-16 encoding, in which each character is encoded
>   as a 16-bit value. UTF-16 characters are called wide characters, to
>   distinguish them from 8-bit ANSI characters. The Visual C++ compiler
>   supports the built-in data type wchar_t for wide characters

Also:

> When Microsoft introduced Unicode support to Windows, it eased the
>   transition by providing two parallel sets of APIs, one for ANSI
>   strings and the other for Unicode strings. [...] Internally, the ANSI
>   version translates the string to Unicode.

Also:

> New applications should always call the Unicode versions. Many world
>   languages require Unicode. If you use ANSI strings, it will be
>   impossible to localize your application. The ANSI versions are also
>   less efficient, because the operating system must convert the ANSI
>   strings to Unicode at run time. [...] Most newer APIs in Windows have
>   just a Unicode version, with no corresponding ANSI version.

Comment: _because we often need cool string features_ ... could be elaborated a bit. Why not use `CString` instead, MFC uses it everywhere? Not that I'd recommend doing so ;-)

Comment: @zett42 - 10 or 20 years ago (yes, I'm so old :-), I'd have recommended that too, but today, there are so many samples/codes/open source/etc. using std:: and also so many people used to it, that I feel ok with std:: however, I see CString as perfectly ok too, as long as you make sure that no one introduces std:: because of lazyness...

Comment: I'll add the comment that in the OP's specific case std::wstring is IMEHO the best choice.  That said, don't make a blind decision to always use std::wstring and wide characters.  Consider what the application is doing before making your choice.  Anecdotally, many years ago (early 2000's IIRC) I took the source to the Dhrystone benchmark, and converted every instance of `char` in it to `wchar_t`.  Doing so resulted in about a 15% slowdown, so be aware that use of wide characters does come with a price.  It's up to you to make the decision regarding whether that price matters to you.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

When programming for Windows, I recommend to use `std::wstring` at least for:

- Resources (Strings, Dialogs, etc.)
- Filesystem access (Windows allows non-ASCII characters in file and directory names (that includes all the "wrong kinds of apostrophes" btw), these are impossible to open using ANSI API)
- COM (a BSTR is always wide character)
- Other user-facing interfaces (clipboard, system error reporting, etc)

However, it is easier to handle *internal ASCII data files* and *UTF-8-encoded-data* using single-character strings. It's fast, efficient and straightforward.

There may also be other aspects that are not mentioned in the question, such as databases or APIs used, input/output files, etc. and their charsets - all of those play a role when deciding on the best data structures for the job.

"UTF-8 everywhere" is a sound idea in general. But there is **0** Windows API that takes UTF-8. Even the `std::experimental::filesystem` API uses `std::wstring` on Windows and `std::string` on POSIX.